# What's the benefits of having a higher skill?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The idea is:

- Every time you level up in Conjuration, it decreases the cost of conjuration spells.
- Every time you level up in One-handed, you increase the damage you do with one handed weapons

And so on. Does anyone knows what are those bonus exactly?

Is there any fix increasing pattern/percentage per level you get on a certain tree?

Comment: Do you mean? "What are the specific bonuses obtained when leveling up a skill? For example, what do I obtain when I level up Archery or Pickpocketing or Heavy Armor?"

Comment: Perhaps more simply, "What's the benefit of having a higher skill?".

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Weapon skills (Archery, One-handed, Two-handed) : skill increases damage done. (0.5% per level. 50% increase at level 100)

Armor skills (Light Armor, Heavy Armor) : skill improves armor rating mildly (perks are where it's really at though). (0.5% per level. 50% increase at level 100)

Magic skills (Alteration, Conjuration, Destruction, Restoration, Illusion) : skill reduces magicka cost.  Skill also unlocks new spells on spell vendors at 25, 50, 75 and 100. (about 41% reduction at level 100)

Lockpicking : skill broadens the target zone.

Pickpocketing : skill increases success chance to pickpocket

Speech : skill improves prices when buying and selling, and increases chance of success for persuade and intimidate.

Sneak : skill reduces detection radius for sight and sound.

Alchemy : skill improves magnitude of potion/poison effects.

Enchanting : skill improves magnitude of enchanting effects.

Smithing : skill improves armor rating of upgrading armor and weapon damage when upgrading.  Does not improve item creation at a forge, only upgrading is affected by skill.

Block : skill increases percent of damage blocked.

Comment: I think he's looking for more exact answers.  As in, what % more damage do you do with a weapon per point of proficiency.

Comment: +1 from me cause I do not need to know the percentages, its nice just knowing what the numbers affect.

Comment: Still would love to see some numbers if anyone knows them though!

Comment: If you want specific numbers, it's possible to find those.  I haven't included them because I can't think of a scenario where you'd make a decision about them.  If you want more damage, more weapon skill is always helpful.  More armor rating, more armor skill.  It's not really a choice.  At the top tier of enchanting with capped skills there are a few choices to make... but if you plan to play the game that long - might as well try out the combinations yourself to suit your play style.