# What effects to does a higher skill level have

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the benefits of having a higher skill?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/45951/whats-the-benefits-of-having-a-higher-skill)

Is there a list of effects for each skill's level. I understand that magic based skills "get easier" as you level them higher as seen [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35750/what-effect-does-increasing-the-magic-skills-have) but what about the other skills?

But what about the others? Archery for instance? Does it level up the damage of any bow? is that reflected in the stats? Or hidden in a formulae for damage?

I'm looking for a concrete list of what happens as each skill gains a level. Not when perks can be unlocked / Higher level items can be purchased.

Comment: Ah, damn the different phrasing, didn't spot that one. Thanks.